# Minimizing diameter of $C_{4n}$ by adding one or two chords.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a cycle with $4n$ nodes where $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and is even.

(a) What minimum diameter can be achieved by adding one chord in $G$?

(b) What minimum diameter can be achieved by adding two chords in $G$?

---

What I observed so far:

Since $G$ has $4n$ vertices the diameter of $G$ is $2n$.

(a) Adding a single edge/chord will not reduce the diameter. Suppose we join two diametrically opposite vertices with a chord, since the number of vertices is $4n$ there will be two more diametrically opposite points that are perpendicular to the current chord that will still have distance $2n$ keeping diameter $2n$. Drawing a chord in any other place will also not reduce the diameter.

(b) Here we draw two chords perpendicular to each other between diametrically opposite points. Since there are $4n$ vertices the remaining $4(n-1)$ vertices will be partitioned into $4$ parts having $n-1$ vertices each. Since $n$ is even $n-1$ will be odd and will have a central vertex. In this case, the diametrical distance will be from that central vertex to the diametrically opposite vertex. And hence the minimum diameter that can be achieved is $n+1$.

[image]

---

Is my argument correct or am I missing something?

Comment: "Perpendicular" doesn't mean anything in graph theory.

Comment: I think in the second case the diameter cannot be made smaller than $n$.

Comment: The argument is not correct in that it does not prove anything about what happens when a different chord or pair of chords is added.